# How would you go about scanning a file in java and counting the number of alphanumerical characters and vowels of that file?

Tags: java, readfile

I've made a scanner which reads the file but then I'm confused on how to count the vowels and letters/numbers. I want to use .chartAt(i) in a for loop but you can't use .charAt() in the Scanner class. Curious to see how to go about this problem

Comment: I'd read the file and count.  Why do you feel you need to use Scanner?

Answer (score 1):

This will count alpha numerical:

```
int alphaNumericCount = input.split("(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])").length - 1;
```

This will count vowels:

```
int vowelCount = input.split("(?<=[AEIOUaeiou])").length - 1;
```

How your read in the file is up to you.